# tabbar with navigation controller iphone application

Tags: iphone

I have created a tabbar with navigation bar iphone application and i added another view which is coming from home tab.The view is coming but the navigation bar and tabbar are not coming.why?

Answer (score 0):

Go in your application's delegate, find the method **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:**.

1. Make sure you set the

   ```
   self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
   ```

   (where tabBarController is your tabbar controller - obviously).
2. Make sure you have the following line right before the end of the method:

   ```
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   ```

Check your main .nib file (MainWindow.xib, probably) and make sure that at least the first TabBar item contains a navigation controller - which opens your view (the one you mentioned).

Hope you sort it out, good luck !